# Why does my code run just fine but in the end of it it always print "None"

Tags: python

There is my code:

```
towel_num = int(input(print("How many towels did he buy? - ")))
```

my code run just fine but at the end of it always prints "None"
Why?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: just this code, i didn't do anything else, it's the start of it

Comment: Remove the `print`. It is not needed. The `input` function will print the text.

Comment: @סער צמח but what is the goal of the code? Do you want to print the users' input?

Comment: @FranciscaConcha-Ramírez No, OP is trying to prompt the user for input. This can be achieved by simply removing the call to `print`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is using print in your input statement:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp

You don't need print, you can just supply the string directly:

```
towel_num = int(input("your message here"))
```

Addendum:

For future reference, in this case, the print function returns None because it has no return of its own.  The input function will display whatever value is provided to it, which in this case is the None returned from print.  If print is used on its own, None does not invoke any response from the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

The `print` function is not needed inside the `input` function. 
If you remove it, the code line works as expected.

**Code:**

```
towel_num = int(input("How many towels did he buy? - "))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
How many towels did he buy? - 5
```